# Can someone explain this macro?

Tags: objective-c, c, macros

I saw this macro [on an Internet page](https://gist.github.com/erikvillegas1/7883183). There is no explanation of what it does.

```
   #define UIColorFromRGB(__HEX__, __A__) [UIColor \
        colorWithRed:((float)((__HEX__ & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
        green:((float)((__HEX__ & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 \
        blue:((float)(__HEX__ & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:__HEX__]
```

I suppose it takes a hexadecimal number on the form `0xRRGGBB` and extracts the `RR`, `GG` and `BB` parts from it, but how exactly is this done?

Or most specifically, how does `(__HEX__ & 0xFF0000) >> 16)` extract the first part of the number?
Sorry but I never understood this `C` stuff well.

Isn't the author wrong by writing `alpha:__HEX__` at the end? shouldn't it be `alpha:__A__`?

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, the author's probably wrong on that last part.  Doing stuff like `(someNumber & 0xF0000) >> 16`, though, is something every programmer should understand -- basic bit-oriented Boolean logic.  Please find a tutorial on Boolean expressions and study it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So lets take the value `0xAABBCC` for the color.

`__HEX__ & 0xFF0000` yields `0xAA0000`. `0xAA0000 >> 16` yields `0xAA`. `0xAA / 255.0` yields `0.6667`. Which is within the value range that `+colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:` is looking for.

`__HEX__ & 0xFF00` yields `0xBB00`. `0xBB00 >> 8` yields `0xBB`. `0xBB / 255.0` yields `0.7333`. Which is within the value range that `+colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:` is looking for.

`__HEX__ & 0xFF` yields `0xCC`. `0xCC / 255.0` yields `0.8`. Which is within the value range that `+colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:` is looking for.

You are right alpha is just wrong. To make things simple, I would just use the raw A value

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(__HEX__, __A__) [UIColor \
    colorWithRed:((CGFloat)(((__HEX__) & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
    green:((CGFloat)(((__HEX__) & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 \
    blue:((CGFloat)((__HEX__) & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:(CGFloat)(__A__)]
```

The expected use would be something like `UIColorFromRGB(0xAABBCC, 0.6)`, this alpha would make the `0xAABBCC` color 60% opaque.

---

**NOTE**

I always wrap macro arguments in parenthesis. This protects against certain types of syntax or logic errors.

`+colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:` expects the type `CGFloat` not `float`.

---

**UPDATE**

More explanation was asked for about bit shifting. So here goes.

`0x32241608` is a number I built it to show `0x32000000` is a 32 bit number, `0x240000` is a 24 but number, `0x1600` is a 16 bit number, and `0x08` is an 8 bit number.

`0x32241608 >> 8` yields `0x322416`. You can think of it as cutting off the 8 bit part of the number.

`0x32241608 >> 16` yields `0x3224`. You can think of it as cutting off the 16 bit part of the number.

`0x32241608 >> 24` yields `0x32`. You can think of it as cutting off the 24 bit part of the number.

`0x32241608 >> 32` yields `0x0`. You can think of it as cutting off the 32 bit part of the number, cutting out the whole number.

Back to my explanation. To get the red value, you need to cut off the 16 bits of the green and blue value. To get the green value, you need to cut off the 8 bits of the blue value.

Hopefully this clears up bit shifting.

Comment: P E R F E C T ! ! ! What I was not realizing "duh" is that AABBCC was a 16 bits number... for some reason my brain was not seeing that. Now I see why the author shifted 16 bits right the first block. Thanks!!!!!

Comment: @DesperateDeveloper AABBCC is a 24bit number. BBCC is 16 bit.

Comment: @JustSid I hope my explanation of bit shifting addresses your concerns about my answer.

Comment: ok, I mistyped. I was talking about shifting it 16 times to the right and put 16 in both places. :)

Comment: @JefferyThomas hi, I still don't see how __HEX__ & 0xFF0000 yields 0xAA0000? Can you explain a little there? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Unheilig 0xFF0000 is a bit [mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)). For each hex digit, if the mask is F, then the original hex digit is returned and if the mask is 0, then 0 is returned. In the example, HEX is 0xAABBCC. 0xAABBCC & 0xFF0000 yields 0xAA0000.